# Making inner div fill column height - works Chrome but not Safari/Firefox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make an inner div fill the height of a column. Bootstrap 4 seems to automatically handle matching the heights of the wrapping col's but when I try adding a height of 100% to the inner divs the column heights get pushed out and expanded really tall... though this issue doesn't seem to happen in Chrome.

Below is the structure I'm using for each column (the row will have multiple instances of these columns) I need NewsSummary to fill the column height without pushing it larger :

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
<div class="NewsSummary same-height">

<div class="NewsSummaryField">
<a href=""> 
<p><img src="" alt="" width="800" height="534"></p>
</a>
</div>


<div class="NewsSummaryLink">
<h2>Text</h2>
</div>

<div class="NewsSummarySummary">
<p>Text...</p>
</div>

<div class="NewsSummaryMorelink">
<p><a href="">More →</a></p>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

Because I'm having trouble with this I also tried to search out a jQuery match height solution but none of the ones I found seem to work, I'm assuming because I'm using jQuery v3 for Bootstrap and its an issue with the code being for older jQ versions... so any pointers to a script that will work would also be useful

Here's a link to a codepen to explain, have slightly simplified the html. You can see I'm trying to achieve a grid type layout which will be of unknown items. I need them to match heights so the background colours on the example align - so in this instance they should expand to the same height as the green one.

https://codepen.io/jwacreative/pen/eYZLEGP

And below is a screen shot of the issue I get of I try and add a height:100% or .h-100 to the NewsSummary div:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9B7F8.png)

Many thanks!

Comment: Now formatted - first time I've used Codepen!

Comment: But your code _here_ isn't formatted. That's what's most important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap has a lot of utility (helper) classes for addressing flex box concerns like equal height. In your case the addition of one simple helper class can address the issue: `.h-100`.

I've simplified your example code even further to demonstrate.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-6 col-lg-4 mb-4">
      <div class="bg-danger p-3 h-100">
        <img src="//placehold.it/300x100" class="w-100 rounded mb-2" />
        <h2>My News Title</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-link">More &#8594;</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  
    <div class="col-6 col-lg-4 mb-4">
      <div class="bg-success p-3 h-100">
        <img src="//placehold.it/300x200" class="w-100 rounded mb-2" />
        <h2>My News Title</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-link">More &#8594;</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-6 col-lg-4 mb-4">
      <div class="bg-warning p-3 h-100">
        <img src="//placehold.it/300x150" class="w-100 rounded mb-2" />
        <h2>My News Title</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-link">More &#8594;</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  
    <div class="col-6 col-lg-4 mb-4">
      <div class="bg-primary p-3 h-100">
        <img src="//placehold.it/300x300" class="w-100 rounded mb-2" />
        <h2>My News Title</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-link">More &#8594;</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

The `.h-100` utility class is explained in more depth on Bootstrap's documentation for their [sizing-related utility classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/sizing/). It applies a 100% height attribute which when combined with flex box will result in the equal height you desire.

Comment: Thanks - I already tried this I'm afraid! If you see in my question this is what I tried at the start but when you view on Safari or Firefox the divs fill 100% of the entire browser height... its not doing that in the codepen though so I dont know whats going on?!

Comment: I'm confused. Do you want your respective columns to all have a height equal to the tallest column, or are you trying to make a set of DIVS take up 100% of the viewport height?  Because your original post suggests the former.

Comment: Yes, the former - all columns should have the same height as the tallest one. NOT take up the height of the viewport - which is what adding h-100 does in Safari/Firefox (but oddly not Chrome). See screenshot, thats whats happening but is not what I want!

Comment: Google Chrome will improperly render the columns if `<!doctype html>` isn't declared. But your CodePen renders as expected on Chrome, Safari, and Firefox.

Comment: Unbelievable! Thats was the issue, I had <!doctype html> commented out in my HTML file!! THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

Based on your codepen code, if you want the height of column the same as the others you can set the set the height of the inner div which is the NewsSummary to 100%.

```css
.NewsSummary {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">


      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-4">
        <div class="NewsSummary same-height" style="background:red">
          <div class="NewsSummaryField">
            image goes here
          </div>

          <div class="NewsSummaryLink">
            <h2>title</h2>
          </div>

          <div class="NewsSummarySummary">
            <p>Text.</p>
          </div>

          <div class="NewsSummaryMorelink">
            <p><a href="">More →</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-4">
        <div class="NewsSummary same-height" style="background:green">
          <div class="NewsSummaryField">
            image goes here
          </div>

          <div class="NewsSummaryLink">
            <h2>title</h2>
          </div>

          <div class="NewsSummarySummary">
            <p>Longer text. Longer text Longer text Longer text Longer text Longer text Longer text Longer text</p>
          </div>

          <div class="NewsSummaryMorelink">
            <p><a href="">More →</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-4">
        <div class="NewsSummary same-height" style="background:yellow">
          <div class="NewsSummaryField">
            image goes here
          </div>

          <div class="NewsSummaryLink">
            <h2>title</h2>
          </div>

          <div class="NewsSummarySummary">
            <p>Text.Longer text Longer text</p>
          </div>

          <div class="NewsSummaryMorelink">
            <p><a href="">More →</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-4">
        <div class="NewsSummary same-height" style="background:purple">
          <div class="NewsSummaryField">
            image goes here
          </div>

          <div class="NewsSummaryLink">
            <h2>title</h2>
          </div>

          <div class="NewsSummarySummary">
            <p>Text.</p>
          </div>

          <div class="NewsSummaryMorelink">
            <p><a href="">More →</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-4">
        <div class="NewsSummary same-height" style="background:blue">
          <div class="NewsSummaryField">
            image goes here
          </div>

          <div class="NewsSummaryLink">
            <h2>title</h2>
          </div>

          <div class="NewsSummarySummary">
            <p>Text.</p>
          </div>

          <div class="NewsSummaryMorelink">
            <p><a href="">More →</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks - I already tried this I'm afraid! If you see in my question this is what I tried at the start but when you view on Safari or Firefox the divs fill 100% of the entire browser height... its not doing that in the codepen though so I dont know whats going on?!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you meant with 'inner div' but you may try it. I set a new row to create a flex div and reset the padding of col-lg-4. In this new row I created a full width column. Remove the style="...", that is for testing only ;-)

If you want all to be browser-full-height, then you have to set `html, body { height: 100%; }` and `same-height` with all its parents to `min-height: 100%;`

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="News_Page row">
      <div class="NewsSummary same-height col-12" style="background:silver">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="News_Page row">
      <div class="NewsSummary same-height col-12" style="background:yellow">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="News_Page row">
      <div class="NewsSummary same-height col-12" style="background:orange">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```